# Why doesn’t Amazon S3 automatically serve /foo/index.html when I ask for /foo or /foo/?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am looking into serving my static site with Amazon S3. I have created a bucket and uploaded my files; under the “Website” tab in the AWS Management Console I have checked “Enabled” and entered `index.html` in the “Index Document” field.  I have the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "924a2348-de0e-43aa-bb06-83adbcd1db22",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]

}
```

where I have my bucket’s name instead of `my-bucket`. Under the “Permissions” tab I have also granted “Everyone” the list ability.

If I try to access `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html` my page (and its images, CSS, etc.) shows up as expected.  However, just going to `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` or `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/` gives a directory-listing XML file instead of showing the page. If I try to go to `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/subdirectory` I get an error (in XML) saying “The specified key does not exist.”  Most bizarrely, if I try to go to `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/subdirectory/` (with a trailing slash), no page loads but my browser downloads an empty file named `download`.  (Once again, going to `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/subdirectory/index.html` shows the page as expected.)

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I get S3 to show the `index.html` file when a directory name is requested?

Comment: This explains a lot: [AWS docs for Website Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure a root (index) document:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html

Comment: I found the problem.  I had already read your second link at some point, but I just went back and re-read it and realized that I was using the wrong domain name.  Instead of expecting my site to be hosted at `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`, which it only sort of was, I should have been using `my-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.  (You can also change the region as appropriate.)  This distinction is obvious now that I know to look for it, but boy, was this subdomain thing glossed over! Anyway, I hope now others will be able to benefit from my inattention :-)

Comment: to know your REAL url, go to `console.aws.amazon.com` and click on the `properties` tab on the top, choose your bucket and there you can see your "endpoint" url

Comment: Also worth noting, if you use the wrong CNAME initially (e.g. my-bucket.s3.amazon.com), don't forget (like I did) that DNS will cache this for a while. :)

Comment: Confirmed. If your CNAME resolves to the root of an S3 bucket (www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com), the `IndexDocumentSupport` simply don't working.

Comment: @wukong Change the CNAME value to "_bucket_.s3-**website**-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", and it should work

Comment: Note that if you're using CloudFront to distribute your static S3 site, you'll also need to set a Default Root Object for the distribution or you'll experience the same issue.

Comment: @Labu Thanks for your comment! 4 years later it helped me get index.html working on a CNAMED S3 bucket!